# jQuery Animated Crop

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, crop

I got this code:

```
<img id="img" src="img.png"/>
<button onclick="crop();">Click me!</button>
```

When the user clicks on the button I'd like to animate the cropping process of the image. The image goes from having a width and height of 100% to having a width and height of 50% (be aware that I'm not talking about stretching, but cropping) in a few seconds.

All of the cropping plugins I've found take quite a while for cropping, and can thus not be used for animation.

Answer (score 1):

Try these Links : (May be helpful)

http://odyniec.net/projects/imgareaselect/

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-create-a-jquery-image-cropping-plugin-from-scratch-part-i/

Comment: Jcrop is working or not ? What about these all plugins ? http://www.pixelzdesign.com/blog_view.php

Comment: Haven't looked into jCrop, I'll do that now, and that link has already been visited

Comment: Seems jCrop isn't quite what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a animate-like function, that supports other wars of transforming images other than stretching (like cropping).

Comment: Ok.jQuery don't have such functionality like animate for image cropping. you may try HTML5 Canvas Image Crop.

Comment: I just figured something out. I'll go with a div, with a background image and overflow:hidden.
Thanks for your time anyway! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#img").animate({'width':'50%', 'height':'50%'}, {queue:false, duration:300});
```

Comment: set the duration what you want.

Comment: That'd stretch not crop it